# How to retrieve email addresses in shipment and billing onepage checkout [magento]

Tags: php, magento

I was looking for solutions on how to retrieve a value from the checkout form of Magento.
I know how to get the billing email through this line of code:

```
{{htmlescape var=$order.getBillingAddress().getEmail()}}
```

but the shipment email is what I can't retrieve. Is there anyway to get it?

Comment: please be precise on what do your want to retreive ?

Comment: Shipping have no email =_='

Comment: we have actually in the form. what I want to retrieve is really the shipment email address, when someone makes an order and check's out then they had to fill up the Onepage checkout where there is a billing and a shipment form.

Comment: what I'm asking is how to just get an input value from the shipment form, that's all because yes I can retrieve most of the values but not the shipment[email] input. or is there a way to add them as part of the possible attributes that I could grab under the order object?.

Answer (score 0):

The shipment entity, or shipping address entity do not have an `email` field. My recommendation is to use the e-mail address from the order object like this:

```
{{var $order.getCustomerEmail()}}
```

**General**
When calling in an e-mail template something like `{{var $object.doSomething()}}` This translates into `$object->doSomething()`. So if you want to see what you can retrieve from the shipment object, just check the methods available in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipping` class and it's parents.